# Photoshop - How detect clipping mask?

Tags: photoshop

I am writing my layout parser.

And faced with one problem, I can not find how to determine that the layer is clipped.

I use this documentation: https://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/photoshop/fileformatashtml/

That's what I'm trying to find.

[image]

Can someone tell me exactly where to look?)

Thank.

Comment: what is mean Detect or DELETE ?

Comment: I need to determine if the layer is using a clipping mask.

Comment: [This](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/66212/is-there-any-way-to-identify-clipping-masks-using-javascript-ps-cs5) may be of use. [This](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/931920) is about creating clipping masks, but should help get you started too

Answer (score -1):

In your example you see an "Arrow" pointing at the box. The box it's pointing at is the 'mask'. Thus the "Grid" is getting clipped by the "rectangle 1".

[image]

So in my example. The gradient is getting clipped, the item below is the mask.

Comment: I know it) I need to determine through the script whether there is a mask or not.